# geom_col not following factor levels or table order when stacking columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a graph of stacked data using `geom_col`

```
df <- structure(list(gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), ST268Q04JA = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("Strongly disagree", 
"Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"), class = "factor"), total = c(-23.7057728119181, 
-38.3985102420857, 31.340782122905, 6.55493482309125, -12.3867069486405, 
-32.4206948640483, 42.4660120845921, 12.726586102719)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can see the data for the plot has the factors in the correct order `"Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree"` and the table itself is sorted in this order as well.

[image]

But when we plot the data, it puts `"Strongly agree"` before `"Agree"`

```
ggplot(plt_data,
         aes(x = gender, y = total, 
             fill= ST268Q04JA)) +
    geom_col(colour="white") +
coord_flip() +
theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When stacking bars `ggplot2` starts with the last category, i.e. your bars are stacked in the order `"Strongly Agree"`, `"Agree"`, `"Disagree"` and `"Strongly Disagree"` (Only because of the the negative values assigned to `"Disagree"` and `"Strongly Disagree"` does it look as if the stack starts with these categories).

While that could be fixed in most cases by reverting the order of the levels or using `position_stack(reverse=TRUE)` this will not work in your case because of the negative values assigned to `"Disagree"` and `"Strongly Disagree"`.

Instead you have to manually set the order so that the bars are stacked in the "correct" or your desired order. In the code below I use a helper column which I map on the `group` aes.

```r
library(ggplot2)

plt_data$ST268Q04JA_group <- factor(
  plt_data$ST268Q04JA,
  c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly agree", "Agree")
)

ggplot(
  plt_data,
  aes(
    x = gender, y = total,
    fill = ST268Q04JA,
    group = ST268Q04JA_group
  )
) +
  geom_col(colour = "white") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]